# Why multiple ESP32 custom PCB on the same RS485 bus are mutually exclusive?

Tags: esp32

I have a 12V LiFP battery BMS (battery management system) connected via a RS485 RTU.

I also designed box (a custom PCB which embed a ESP32 as the main CPU) that report the battery SoC (State of charge) thru the LEDs strip (and many others values).

When I connect more than one box to the RS485 bus, I see that only one get the RS85 messages, while others receive nothing.

When I disconnect the one which receives the packets, another one all of a sudden receives the packets, the still-connected others do not.

Here is a schematics:

[image]

Here are the photos of each steps:

1. The first shows the initial connection: only one is connected and received packets, the SoC (almost 100% here) is displayed by the LEDs strip.

[image]

2. The second photo shows the situation when after I have connected the second PCB: we see that the new one could not get the RS485 packets (it shows the blue-white-red flag waiting-for-RS485 packets signal).

[image]

3. The third photo shows the last situation after I disconnected the first PCB:  we see that the remaining PCB picked up the RS485 packets and show the SoC.

[image]

What would be the reason why not all connected PCB can get the RS485 packets?

Comment: There are so very many things that could be going wrong here, from hardware to software, it's impossible to say based on what you've posted. The first thing to do would be to confirm the RS485 hardware, make sure that it's designed and built correctly and that the signals are at the correct levels. You'd want to use an oscilloscope and maybe logic analyzer to do that. If you confirm that your RS485 implementation is working correctly then it's time to dig into the software.

Comment: One of the devices has become the master perhaps. See what library these are implementing for the RS485. See whether it supports master selection and whether the messages you're sending are going to either just the master or just the slave.